# 'Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error' when installing numpy on VS code (Fantasy Football Data Pros: Data Munging with Pandas)

Tags: python, numpy

So I was trying to install numpy 1.20.3, on VS Code, when it says:

```
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [239 lines of output]
      setup.py:66: RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.20.3 may not yet support Python 3.10.
        warnings.warn(
      Running from numpy source directory.
      setup.py:485: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
        run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
      C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\tools\cythonize.py:67: DeprecationWarning: The distutils package is deprecated and slated for removal in Python 3.12. Use setuptools or check PEP 632 for potential alternatives
        from distutils.version import LooseVersion
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
      Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
      Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
      Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
      Cythonizing sources
      blas_opt_info:
      blas_mkl_info:
      No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
      customize MSVCCompiler
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      blis_info:
        libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
      get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
      customize GnuFCompiler
      Could not locate executable g77
      Could not locate executable f77
      customize IntelVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable ifort
      Could not locate executable ifl
      customize AbsoftFCompiler
      Could not locate executable f90
      customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable DF
      customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efl
      customize Gnu95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable gfortran
      Could not locate executable f95
      customize G95FCompiler
      Could not locate executable g95
      customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
      customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
      Could not locate executable efort
      Could not locate executable efc
      customize PGroupFlangCompiler
      Could not locate executable flang
      don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_blas_info:
        libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_blas_info:
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
          Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
          Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
          A better performance should be easily gained by switching
          Blas library.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_info:
        libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
          the BLAS environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
      blas_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1989: UserWarning:
          Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
          the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
        if self._calc_info(blas):
        NOT AVAILABLE

      non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
      lapack_opt_info:
      lapack_mkl_info:
        libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_lapack_info:
        libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      openblas_clapack_info:
        libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      flame_info:
        libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_3_10_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_threads_info:
      Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      atlas_info:
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib
        libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
        libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
        NOT AVAILABLE

      lapack_info:
        libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\_\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\VOR-Models\\2021-VOR-Model\\venv\\lib', 'C:\\']
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
          Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
          the LAPACK environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      lapack_src_info:
        NOT AVAILABLE

      C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1849: UserWarning:
          Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
          Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
          numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
          the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
        return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
        NOT AVAILABLE

      numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
        FOUND:
          language = c
          define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

      C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      running dist_info
      running build_src
      build_src
      building py_modules sources
      creating build
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy
      creating build\src.win-amd64-3.10\numpy\distutils
      building library "npymath" sources
      LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "C:\Users\_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fmnw10id\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 157, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fmnw10id\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 248, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fmnw10id\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 142, in run_setup
          exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
        File "setup.py", line 513, in <module>
          setup_package()
        File "setup.py", line 505, in setup_package
          setup(**metadata)
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
          return old_setup(**new_attr)
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fmnw10id\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 165, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fmnw10id\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\dist_info.py", line 31, in run
          egg_info.run()
        File "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\command\egg_info.py", line 24, in run
          self.run_command("build_src")
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 144, in run
          self.build_sources()
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 155, in build_sources
          self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 288, in build_library_sources
          sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
        File "C:\Users\_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-12pl1k89\numpy_a61d254ad189429092d1fab3dbdca78f\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 378, in generate_sources
          source = func(extension, build_dir)
        File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 676, in get_mathlib_info
          raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
      RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I am installing it like this:

(venv) PS C:\Users_\OneDrive\Desktop\VOR-Models\2021-VOR-Model> pip install -r requirements.txt

Because I am so lost, I will show you requirements.txt. This function literally installs everything before numpy, then it fails.

```
clearbeautifulsoup4==4.9.3
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
idna==2.10
numpy==1.20.3
pandas==1.2.4
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
soupsieve==2.2.1
urllib3==1.26.5
```

Any help is appreciated. The reason I am doing this is because I took a course online (https://www.fantasyfootballdatapros.com/), and am trying to do data munging with pandas. I need NumPy for that. I also tried looking at other questions, but they didn't give me the answers I needed, or didn't have an answer at all. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community Thank you. I tried to clarify this in my answer, but if not understood, here: Basically, I need to install NumPy from a txt file called requirements.txt, and It worked for installing anything else. The reason I need NumPy is because I am taking a course that requires you to install specific packages and specific versions. The course is for Data Munging With Pandas. Except, when it tries to install NumPy, it gives me an error on preparing metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says it in the error message.

> RuntimeWarning: NumPy 1.20.3 may not yet support Python 3.10.

Two quick trys:

1. Without looking through each packages, try removing numpy from requirements, and run "python -m pip install -r requirements.txt" again.  Then in command line, try typing this to see if it installed because the other packages (ex. Tensorflow install numpy automatically, with the version it depends on).

> python -m numpy

2. try a lower numpy version.  inside requirments.txt try typing  or something under 1.20.3

> numpy==1.19.2

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me. So, I deleted the version of my numpy. Then, the requirements.txt worked well.

```
text-unidecode==1.3
icecream==2.1.1
datetime==4.3
numpy     
python-dotenv==0.19.0
flask
bigquery==0.0.15   
google-cloud==0.34.0                   
google-cloud-bigquery>=2.14.0                                              
gspread==3.0.1
gcsfs==2021.6.1
pandas-gbq==0.15.0
ipython==7.5.0
```

Comment: Although this can solve the problem, the OP asked for a specific version of numpy, remove the version from de requirements.txt will not install the specific version.

Comment: It solved me the numpy installation with python 3.11, but got stuck with other errors during installation of spacy==3.0.6

Answer (score 0):

If you use python 3.10 , the numpy version 1.24.2 should work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).